# insert into BigQuery nested tables from 2 individual tables

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery, nested

I have 2 individual tables, trying to insert into a 3rd table which is nested (ARRAY and STRUCT) using insert ... select statement

individual tables:
USERS (userid, firstname, lastname)

ADDRESSES (userid, street, city, state)

nested table:
MEMBERS (userid, firstname, lastname, addresses)

each user can have multiple addresses, key is userid

Looking for something like INSERT INTO MEMBERS (userid, firstname, lastname, addresses) SELECT userid, firstname, lastname, (ARRAY STRUCT of addresses)

I expect all users to be inserted into the nested tables, and each user can have multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below Query

ARRAY_AGG is the Grouping Function to group multiple STRUCT records into a Repeated Structure

```
INSERT INTO MEMBERS 
  (userid, firstname, lastname, addresses)
SELECT
  u.userid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(m.street, m.city, m.state)) AS addresses
FROM USERS u
     LEFT JOIN MEMBERS m
       ON (m.userid = u.userid)
GROUP BY
  u.userid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname;
```